# VLCJ dynamically modify frames while streaming

Tags: java, video-streaming, streaming, libvlc, vlcj

My project has two parts. First one is to stream a video and second is to capture streamed video and analyze it. it's been done the capture and analyze side.

While i'm doing this, I've made a workaround for my question; i convert video into `BufferedImage`s and saved to image files. Then i edit images files and convert back to video again. Finally i can stream edited video and do the other capture and analyze part.

But since this workaround is a long-timed process and frame edits must be done simultaneously and dynamically according to my real-life use, i must interfere just before the frames are being streamed.

I made lots of searching but maybe i'm not familiar with streaming and its terms and couldn't find a way to do it with vlcj and java. Actually, to solve this problem, I don't necessarily have to stick with java and vlcj. If vlcj doesn't provide a solution, all other suggestions are will be fine.

And here is the code i use to stream from a video file below;

```
private void Stream () throws InterruptedException {

      String media = "C:\\someVideo.mp4";
      String options = formatRtpStream("127.0.0.1", 5555);

      MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
      EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.mediaPlayers().newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
      mediaPlayer.media().prepare(media,
              options,
              ":no-sout-rtp-sap",
              ":no-sout-standard-sap",
              ":sout-all",
              ":sout-keep"
      );
   }

   private static String formatRtpStream(String serverAddress, int serverPort) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(200);
      sb.append(":sout=");
      sb.append("#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=1000,fps=25,scale=1,noaudio}");
      sb.append(":rtp{dst=");
      sb.append(serverAddress);
      sb.append(",port=");
      sb.append(serverPort);
      sb.append(",mux=ts}");
      return sb.toString();
   }
```

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but if you want to capture the video frames then rather than creating BufferedImages you should look into the so-called "direct" or "callback" media players provided by vlcj - those media players give you direct access to the native video buffer which you can save/process.

Comment: @caprica Thank you. I couldn't find and able to create a directMediaPLayer instance. I'm using the version: '4.7.0'.
Also, with CallbackMediaPlayerComponent, couldn't be able to access to the 'native video buffer'. May you point me how can i do that please? I've found a method called `setImagePainter(imagePainter)` and i set it and wasn't triggered while player was streaming.

Comment: @caprica Also i've found [this](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/component/CallbackMediaPlayerComponent2Test.java) and i've implemented  `DefaultBufferFormatCallback` and `DefaultRenderCallback` but they weren't invoked while the player was streaming again.
Also i tried to get v5.0.0 from maven and maven couldn't resolve that dependencies.

Comment: Oh ok, so if you're streaming there is nothing to "display" locally then those callbacks indeed won't be called. I don't have any other answer.

Comment: @caprica I was afraid of this 'displaying locally' thing. Thank You.